# 3-legged OAuth token from command line

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, command-line-interface

How would one go about supporting 3-legged OAuth workflows from a custom command line tool?

I would like to allow the users of my CLI tool to go online, log in, and have the token cached locally, similarly to what [heroku login](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli#getting-started) is doing.

Comment: depends on the auth server you should just be able to send the same auth requests to the server that you would normally.  Someone is still going to have to open the consent screen in a web browser there will be no way around that.

Comment: Yep, the idea was that the CLI tool would open a web browser with the consent screen, similarly to how the `heroku login` command opens a browser with the login form. But then, how should one handle the callback from the auth server? Maybe by having the CLI tool include a simple http server and use something like ngrok?

Answer (score 1):

You have to go throw the consent screen.
You can do it with electron, here is an [example](https://www.manos.im/blog/electron-oauth-with-github/) for Github OAuth.
So you write code that open electron on the OAuth endpoint and grab the cookies from electron.

But if you want 3-legged you have to have a server.
so you can either setup a  public server that handle the request (defined as the redirect URL for your app), return the access token and catch it from the code that opened electron (if you set it as cookies it will also be cached).
If you don't want a public server, you can set the redirect URL to localhost and open both electron and a local web server.